# How is the presenter created in MVP?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, mvp, android-mvp

I was looking at the google samples for MVP and I saw [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/taskdetail/TaskDetailActivity.java#L65) as the last statement in `onCreate` of the activity:

```
new TaskDetailPresenter(  
                taskId,  
                Injection.provideTasksRepository(getApplicationContext()),  
taskDetailFragment);
```

This code seems weird to me.
It instantiates an object ([TaskDetailPresenter](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/taskdetail/TaskDetailPresenter.java#L33)) that is local and not assigned anywhere and in it associates the [fragment](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/taskdetail/TaskDetailFragment.java#L63) with the presenter.
Classes defined [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/taskdetail)
Is this really how it is supposed to be done? Because it seems not a good practice to me

Comment: what code is there inside the constructor of `TaskDetailPresenter` ?

Comment: @nits.kk: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/taskdetail/TaskDetailPresenter.java#L45

Comment: @nits.kk:I updated post

Answer (score 2):

In `TaskDetailPresenter` constructor they have:

```
mTaskDetailView.setPresenter(this);
```

So the presenter object is passed to the fragment ("View" in MVP). And that fragment stores a reference to the presenter. This is ok - View can easily communicate with its presenter with this configuration.

But the trick they use here - calling `setPresenter(this)` before the constructor finishes is a bad thing. Here you can find an explanation of this problem: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=252

It may be ok if that reference is just saved to a property and everything happens in one thread. But something may change in the future and we can get into trouble.

Comment: So the fact that the `new TaskDetailPresenter(..)` is a local variable to the variable to that function that goes out of scope after the body of the method is not relevant because the view keeps a reference to that presenter? Also this seems usual approach in online mvp examples I googled for android

Comment: @Jim yep, it’s not relevant because the view keeps a reference to the presenter and this prevents it from being garbage collected.